# Is it possible to run a Dockerfile without building an image (or to immediately/transparently discard the image)?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a use case where I call `docker build .` on one of our build machines.

During the build, a volume mount from the host machine is used to persist intermediate artifacts.

I don't care about this image at all. I have been tagging it with `-t` during the build and calling `docker rmi` after it's been created, but I was wondering if there was a one-liner/flag that could do this.

The `docker build` steps [don't seem to have an appropriate flag for this behavior](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), but it may be simply because `build` is the wrong term.

Comment: If you don't want to build an image or otherwise affect Docker artifacts at all, is Docker the right tool?  Why not do this task with a shell script or Makefile?

Comment: I'd say no and yes: No to the purist POV, yes to the "do your job without artificial constraints". I don't have control over our build servers to install frameworks/tools I might need, and the team that does is notoriously slow at doing so. Using Docker (which is installed) as a crutch puts the power back in my hands as a developer and allows me to run frameworks/executables in a sandboxed way without getting them involved.

Comment: At build point, you did not run your container yet... so are you like never planning to run the container at all? If you plan to run it at some point, then you need your image to do so.

Comment: I am not planning to ever run this container. I am using the Dockerfile as a poor man's VM. The Dockerfile is solid, and I only stopped caring about the image it created recently - I'm trying to just reuse something I know works 100% (and be responsible by not leaving the useless image's bits on the filesystem) before I port the Dockerfile syntax to a Makefile/Bash